# Compare Excel files and keep only different rows

Tags: excel

I have two Excel sheets that contain many matching rows, and I want to keep only the rows that are different (based on the ID column). I don't want to simply remove duplicates; I want to eliminate all matching rows.
So everytime I find a duplicate, I'll be removing both matching rows.

Can you please advise me on how to accomplish this?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Flag duplicate rows with a helper column, filter on these then remove them? For a more detailed answer, we'd need sample data and expected outcome. What you current code is would also be useful.

Comment: Show us data example and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an aproach I would use:

1. Copy both sheets into a third one.
2. Select all cells and create a table with sortable headers (should be Ctrl+T).
3. With all ID column selected, go to conditional formating -> Higlight -> Duplicates
4. After duplicates are highlighted, sort the column ascending.
5. Now you can select the first N rows (duplicating values), go to Delete -> Delete Sheet Rows

And you should be left with only non duplicating values.

Another approach would be:

1. Use a single sheet and turn it into a table with sortable headers.
2. Add an additional column for occurance count.
3. Use the formula COUNT to see how many times the current ID occurs in the ID column.
4. Filter the table to show only values of '1' (non duplicating IDs) and you qill have only the rows with the unique ID.